# Causality MA(1) process

Tags: functions, stochastic-processes, time-series

Given is the MA(1) process:

$X_t = Z_t + \theta Z_{t-1}$

Where,

$Z_t \sim WN(0,1)$

For what values of $\theta$ is $X_t$ a causal function?

I know how to show causality for a AR(p) process with use of the backshift operator, but in this case I don't see how to solve it. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: always.  causality is not an issue with MA processes.  There is an analgous feature called 'inveritbility'  that you worry about for MA processes.  That one is invertible for $| \theta | < 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For what values of θ is Xt a causal function?

Always, by definition. Note that $X_t$ is measurable with respect to $(W_t,W_{t-1})$ hence also measurable with respect to the past sigma-algebra $\sigma(W_s;s\leqslant t)$.